# How to easily organise your Blender scene?

Tags: scene, groups, parent, layers

When making complex scenes there should be some kind of "folders" (i.e. like in Adobe Photoshop, layer management) in scene outliner, that can group objects together - but this feature seems not present.

Is there some addon or way to manage scene "like a pro"? I find groups very unfriendly and object parenting is somehow useful, but not quite good in my opinion for right scene organisation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For **scene organization** and layout have a look into the new [**Collection System**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/introduction.html) introduced as of Blender 2.80. Collections are essentially like folders, they are artist friendly and can even be instanced. There is also a [Collection Manager](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/collection_manager.html) add-on shipped by default which allows to quickly enable or disable collections directly in the 3d View and a lot more:

[image]

Notice that you can have multiple windows of the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/editors/outliner/introduction.html) and set each to whatever object/data type is required in your situation by using the [Filter menu](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/outliner.html#filter) in the header:

[image]

---

For versions pre 2.8, I'd suggest use the [layer management addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/layer_manager) for a better **scene organization**, which is shipped with blender by default:

[image]

In addition, the *Outliner* provides some functionality to **display the desired data types** like *Groups*, *Same Objects*, *Selected Objects* etc.:

[image]

Comment: I've just tested it :) Splitting outliner into two views: Current Scene and Groups with this addon really helps in this case! :)

Comment: @komorra Great! Glad I could help.