# Hide/Show specific object groups only

Tags: objects, scene, groups

Is there a way to hide/unhide objects that are part of a group without effecting anything else?

I'm animating a scene (to see what's involved in animation) and since its to heavy to work with I have a low-poly version of it for real-time purposes (with the same armatures for characters and stuff). They are all grouped ("low-poly" group and "high-poly" group) and I want to be able to switch between them as I work.

The problem is that when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (to unhide objects), both the "High-poly" and "Low-poly" groups are shown.

Is there a way to make it group specific?

Comment: In the Outliner, you can select Groups option to show groups presented in .blend and click "Eye" icon next to it just like for any object..

Comment: @Mr Zak Exactly what I need! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36533/how-to-easily-organise-your-blender-scene/36535#36535

Comment: @poor It's about time I'm a little organized. Thanks for sharing

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to exchange the groups by animating the visibility, [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38437/3710) might also be helpful.